# Is there any way to know if specific part of binary/file is in-memory at a moment?

Tags: c++, winapi, memory-management, in-memory

What win32 APIs are useful to code a tool as described here:

My goal is a tool that can be used to check/report if a specific part of a file is located/available in-memory (RAM) or in virtual memory (disk) at a moment ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>[VirtualQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)</strike> [QueryWorkingSetEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684949%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) does that, specifically the Locked bit in PSAPI_WORKING_SET_EX_BLOCK. VirtualQuery as I've incorrectly pointed out initially merely lets you tell whether pages are committed and such, not whether they're actually in physical RAM.   For Linux, it would be [mincore](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mincore.2.html), which simply returns a byte vector (LSB == 1 for in-core).

Note that the information you get is a snapshot, which means the information may in principle already be outdated at the time the function returns (much like GetCurrentProcessorNumber).
So, treat the information as a (probably more or less accurate, but unreliable) hint, not a guarantee.

Comment: Which of the returned values corresponds to the answer? As far as I can see, all you get is `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION`. That tells you something about the range, not individual pages, and certainly not whether they're currently swapped out to disk. E.g. `MEM_COMMIT: pages for which physical storage has been allocated, either in memory or in the paging file` - so no distinction.

Comment: You're right, I confused the functions (got the Linux one right, but the Windows one wrong). Will update.

Comment: And that doesn't work, because it only tells you which pages are "locked" in memory (are non-pageable). That's fairly stable; being locked exactly means they're not swapped out to disk at a whim. But it's also a rare exception; most pages in RAM are _not_ locked in any way and are candidates for paging. Doesn't answer the question here (see also comment on my answer, which explains the real goal)

Comment: @Damon: thank u very much. I will consider MSalters comments.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't exist, for a simple reason. The answer could change *while* the API function returns. (Also, the answer often is "yes and yes".)

Comment: Even by kernel level programming? What I want is just to calculate a percentage of how many time a part is loaded to/unloaded from memory.

Comment: Why don't you use Event Tracing for Windows (ETW) for that? And you really should have asked that question, instead of the current one.

Comment: I will take a look for ETW. Thanks.